# RGBDSLAM Map Update

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using the RGBDSLAM package with a Kinect.

The thing is that I would like to know if the map it's supposed to be updated when recording a previously visited position, because when an object is taken from a visited frame and I record it again, the object is still there and the map is not updated, but if I add an object in a frame while recording it will appear. So it seems that the map is rather adding information than updating it.

Cheers,
Aridane

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/101671/rgbdslam-map-update/) by [Aridane](https://answers.ros.org/users/8841/aridane/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2013-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I guess you are talking about the point cloud, which only represents the measured points. For the reason you state people use probabilistic occupancy maps, which consider the implicit "free space" between perceived point and sensor.
RGBDSLAM uses the octomap library to create such an occupancy map. In this map the removed object will (slowly) be erased, when you revisit the place where it has been. You can either save the point-cloud as octomap when you are done, or create it online.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2013-12-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aridane](https://answers.ros.org/users/8841/aridane/) on 2013-12-08**:
I see, I will work with the octomap then, thank you for your answer!